# How can I enable fast file transfers across devices connected over the same network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, transfer

I am building a pdf making solution in which a user captures photos from his camera, and s/he can make a pdf out of those photos. Now my client wants a feature where you can share photos captured in one device to another device (like if the user is capturing photos on a mobile device and he now wants those photos on another device maybe a computer). The whole app is a progressive web app, so pretty much all functionalities run offline. I thought about building a web server, and upload photos on prompt from the mobile device, and may be provide some way for the pc to connect and download those files. But turns out it gets too slow..

But then I thought there are some web apps, which allow sharing large files after connecting to the same wifi network, how do they do that? For now that seems like the solution for my problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can have a webserver running in the local network too. It's probably WAY faster.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @MoshFeu I need this solution on the web. Not just on a local area.

Comment: `which allow sharing large files after connecting to the same wifi network`. If you need it be on the public internet, it will be slower. You can try webRCT (e.g. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/) but it still depends on the devices vendors internet speed.

Comment: lemme help you understand what I'm thinking. Have you used apps like shareit, where they allow two devices to share files without internet. I want something like that, on the web. d

Comment: I don't know and I also can't imagine how you can transfer files between devices with them to be connected somehow. I do understand id they are connected with internet such as BT or over a local network. But I'm not an networks expect so I'm probably missing a lot.